# How can I mirror an SVN trunk repository into a regular network folder?

Tags: svn, backups

Me and a small team of engineers are considering using SVN to store our electrical schematics and parts libraries; currently we just have a network folder where we put all of our files. Our company also has a separate SVN server that we have access to.

I was wondering if there was some way that we could use the SVN repository to store our files and schematics, but then somehow have the trunk SVN repository be automatically mirrored into a non-SVN network folder like we currently have.

The reason I am asking for this is because sometimes non-technical people need to access our schematic data, and we don't have enough resources to teach everyone how to use SVN. This way we could have everything under revision control, as well as allowing other people to continue accessing the data in the same way that they are used to.

Comment: cron job running "svn update"

Comment: ... or better svn export (especially when you have people don't understand svn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the SVN server is [hosted with Apache](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.apache), the files and folders can be accessed with normal http or https URLs. This should be as easy to use as the current network drive for those who don't want to learn or install SVN client.